# how can i use javascript without JSNI in GWT 2.4

Tags: javascript, gwt

I have a hand-written jquery javascript which is extended from the latest version. It's not in the GWTQuery or GWTQuery-UI. I know JSNI could inject any javascipt, but I don't want to use it because it's too rigid if I want to change and test something.

Is there any way I can use the it directly in the UIBinder template xml file?

Comment: How would UiBinder be different from JSNI re. "too rigid if I want to change and test something"? Maybe have a look at `ScriptInjector`, or simply a `<script src=""/>` in your *.gwt.xml

Comment: I tried, It's not allowed to use the <script src=""/> in the *.gwt.xml. And the script shouldn't go to he host html file either because my onLoad script only apply to one of the place, not the host html itself.

Comment: Yes it is: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects#DevGuideAutomaticResourceInclusion but it won't be that different from putting it in your host page. Have you looked at ScriptInjector? (but again: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by "rigid")

Comment: I will try again. "Rigid" means that I have to put my js code in the java code, compile the unit and populate it. One of my concern is that takes at least 1 minutes. It's a painful process if I want to keep changing one part. Another general concern of GWT is that sometime I found some type of change can't be hot-deployed under dev mode for some reason.

Comment: Sorry, I mean not allowed in the ui.xml file. Putting into the gwt.xml file it not what I want because I need the jquery selector running on specific page. By saying "rigid", I mean it takes time to change the js, build and hot deploy it.

Comment: Including it inside a UiBinder template wouldn't change anything, so you've been asking the wrong question. Then again: have a look at ScriptInjector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support for Javascript in UiBinder.

If you want to call Javascript you need to use JSNI. Testing problems can be avoided by using two different implementations.

If you are concerned about development turn around time you might want to take a look at super dev mode.

Comment: Frankly, I won't try this experimental replacement. You spend lots of time and finally you find it's just the bug of tool itself. I still don't understand why GWT can't provide a way to just directly use the javascript in the UIBinder.

Comment: there are technical reasons for that. What should happen if you use the widget several times? Inject the script several times or only once?

Comment: I guess it could be injected several times. And since they are all static, technically it just be appended rather than injected. For the UIBinder it just very small overhead.  It could be processed like the standard htmltags inside <g:HTMLPanel>. Maybe I just naive.